# Notepad++ Как выделить текст в каждом столбце по отдельности?

Tags: notepad++

Как выделить для копирования только левый или только правый столбец с текстом, если есть очень много строк по типу?:

```
hi.    привет.
we.    мы.
no.    нет.
yes.   да.
...    и тд.
```

Разделение между словами в строках - TAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Включить мультиредактирование]

Надо включить мультиредактирование. С зажатым Ctrl можно выделять разные фрагменты, а с зажатым Alt выделить столбец

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.